# How to POST the HTML Form in Opera Mini and Opera Mobile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, opera-mini, opera-mobile

There is an ASP.NET 4.0 website and this is for mobile phones.
Since, still many mobiles do not have Javascript support I used Native FROM. I've prepared a test page and here it is:

In test.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="test2.aspx" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ckeck1"/>
        <input type="text" value="test" id="btnText" name="btnText"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In test.aspx.cs file there is nothing.
In the post page Test2.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer == null || !Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("test.aspx"))
            Response.Redirect("test.aspx?p=" + Request.QueryString["packagecode"] + "&requestId=" + Request.QueryString["requestId"]);

        if (Request.Form["ckeck1"] != null)
            Response.Write(Request.Form["ckeck1"].ToString() + "<br>");
        if (Request.Form["btnText"] != null)
            Response.Write(Request.Form["btnText"].ToString() + "<br>");
        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            Response.Write("Url: " + Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri + "<br>");
    }
```

The code is working just fine with almost all mobile browsers..

But, in **OPERA MINI** and **OPERA MOBILE**, this code **does NOT POST** instead it just refreshes the page.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. And here are the things we must have paid attention:
1) No GET, only POST

```
<form id="form1" action="test2.aspx" method="POST">
```

2) Opera browsers CANNOT read CSS 3.0 - And because of that, it displays the page but CANNOT POST at all...

I used to like Opera back in 2003 or 2004, and I guess I found one more reason not to like it.